# shell script not running but just exiting

Tags: shell

I am trying to run the following shell script, but its exiting without flashing any error ( I am ignoring the program errors but not shell errors).

```
#!/bin/bash
export TIMEFORMAT="%E"
rm -f mix_histogram
x=1
d=0
while read y
do
d=$(( $(( $d + 1 )) % 2 ))
(time echo '\n' | /home/pallavi/cudaSamples/3_Imaging/histogram 0 >/dev/null 2>/dev  /null) > /dev/null 2>> mix_histogram &
t1=$(echo "l(32768)" | bc -l)
t2=$(echo "l(($y))" | bc -l)
t=$(echo "( $t1 - $t2 )" | bc -l)
t=$(echo "( 25 * $t )" | bc -l)
t=$(echo "($t)" | bc)
if [ $(echo "200 < $t"|bc) -eq 1 ]
then
   t=200
fi
sleep $t
done < stream1_50
wait
```

could anybody tell me why its not executing??

Comment: Error in 9th line `/dev/null 2>/dev  /null` it's `/dev/null`.Delete the space between `/dev` and `/null`

Answer (score 0):

How do you know it is not executing?

In such cases, the following is helpful: Run the script this way

```
bash -x path/to/your/script
```

This will show an execution trace on standard error.